# how to navigate adorner when click button

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I create a sample of adorner to inform client the use usage of each component.
What i want to ask is, how do i move the control/adorner to other component.
in the picture when i click the help button,it show the adorner. how do i move the adorner to the `textedit2` purple square. the adorner using usercontrol.
this is the form1 code

[image]

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AdornerUIManager1.ShowGuides = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True

End Sub

Private Sub AdornerUIManager1_QueryGuideFlyoutControl(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Utils.VisualEffects.QueryGuideFlyoutControlEventArgs) Handles AdornerUIManager1.QueryGuideFlyoutControl
    If e.SelectedElement.TargetElement Is Button1 Then
        e.Control = New LabelControl() With {
    .AllowHtmlString = True,
    .Width = 350,
    .AutoSizeMode = LabelAutoSizeMode.Vertical,
    .Padding = New Padding(20),
    .Text = "<b>Navigation Bar</b><br>" & "A side navigation control that supports integration with Office Navigation Bar<br><br>" & "Shows navigation options for your currently selected module"}
    End If
    If e.SelectedElement.TargetElement Is TextEdit1 Then
        Dim x As New UserControl1
        x.Label1.Text = "xxXXXxx"
        x.WindowsUIButtonPanel1.Buttons(0).Properties.Checked = True
        e.Control = x
    End If
End Sub
```

this is the usercontrol code

```
Public Class UserControl1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As Form1
    x.AdornerUIManager1.Elements(0).TargetElement = x.TextEdit3
End Sub
End Class
```

when i try to click, it got error

[image]

Comment: Whats the error, you didnt mention that...

Comment: @Codexer i forgot. i thinks it due to no `new` in `Dim x As Form1`. but i still can't get to other element